# How to move the button to the center?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Following code creates a `JDialog` with `BoxLayout`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Border border1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 5);

JDialog j7=new JDialog();
JPanel j8=new JPanel();
JButton j10=new JButton("OK");
BoxLayout c1=new BoxLayout(j8,1);
j8.setLayout(c1);
j8.setBorder(border1);
JLabel j9=new JLabel("Yeeks!!Game was about to crash.We managed it.Numbers Only!");
j9.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
j8.add(j9);
j8.add(j10,1);
j7.add(j8);
Dimension d=new Dimension(710,200);
j7.setSize(d);
j7.setTitle("Humans");
j7.setEnabled(true);


j7.setVisible(true);

j7.setLocation(400, 200);

}
```

How do I center the `JButton`?

One more problem is that the components are not resizing when I change the size of the JDialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to center a component on a frame/dialog is to use a GridBagLayout.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
panel.add(new JButton("Centered"), new GridBagConstraints());
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you want to use a BoxLayout, then you need to add "glue" before the first component and after the last. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information.

Comment: Is it not possible with `BoxLayout` ?

Comment: and why are the components not resizing when JDialog is resized?

Comment: See update. I don't know what you expect to happen on resizing. The BoxLayout respects the maximum size of a component.